# Multiple waypoints in Apple Map

Tags: apple-maps

Is there a way to show routes between multiple points in Apple map like Google map programmatically?

[image: multiple waypoints in google Map]

Comment: My question is also same...

Comment: Hey Dhaval! Did you find any answer???

Answer (score 1):

As MKMapItem documentation states:

> If you specify the MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey option in the
>   launchOptions dictionary, the mapItems array must have no more than
>   two items in it. If the array contains one item, the Maps app
>   generates directions from the user’s current location to the location
>   specified by the map item. If the array contains two items, the Maps
>   app generates directions from the location of the first item to the
>   location of the second item in the array.

So the answer is no.